# Magnetic flux density a small distance off axis from a current loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

I'm currently studying physics at University and struggling with the problem mentioned, it's on a past paper I'm trying to do.

I have calculated the B field on axis as (sorry don't know how to format this yet)

$$B = \mu \frac{Ia^2 }{2(a^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$$

In the $z$ direction.

The question then asks:

> At a small distance ($\rho\ll a$) off axis near the point $A=(0,0,z)$, the diverging magnetic flux density has a component perpendicular to the axis. Find this'
>   [image: Diangram of setup]

Should I use $\nabla\cdot\mathbf B=0$ then try and solve? Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Not quite sure, what this question is actually asking. Are you looking for the magnetic field? If so I would set up the general integrals and solve the limiting case. You should find some hints for instance in: http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/materials/StudyGuide/guide09.pdfCtSksQSesoCwCw&usg=AFQjCNEAVQdgQEMDk-eil8j8DGkPx9-brw

Comment: If you are looking for the magnetic flux density, well why should it diverge? I don't see anything diverging in this problem ;-)

Comment: and you could get the same approximation as in my first comment by just by using geometry. If you want to go this way, think of the magnetic field vectors from every element of the loop to the point off the axis. They will all have the same magnitude, but different directions. Set up a general expression for them parameterized in terms of the angle and then integrate over all of them.

Comment: did you manage to find an answer? I cannot access the link posted by @ftiaronsem in the first comment.

Comment: I tried using $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0 $ ending up with $B_\rho \propto k\rho$ but I am unsure if this is correct

Comment: hmm looks like the link broke. Here is the updated link: http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide09.pdf Look at section 9.8 Appendix 1 and in particular at equations (9.8.7) and (9.8.8) . Keep in mind that $\rho<<a$